# The data is not able to get stored in realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am entering the users name and phone number by making a child "Users"and another child inside that Phone number(mnum).

I have put an `addOnCompleteListener` Which Tells me if the task is successful or not.

It always says that the task is not successful and as i have added the Toast "Network Error" it shows me Network Error When i Try to add data to the database

```
 private void AddAcc(final String nam, final String mnum)
  {
    final DatabaseReference Rootref;
    Rootref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(mnum).exists())) {
                HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
                userDataMap.put("Name", nam);
                userDataMap.put("Phone No.", mnum);
                Rootref.child("Users").child(mnum).updateChildren(userDataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });


            } else {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Number is Already Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

No matter what i do It always pops up the toast "Network Error"

Comment: Instead of keeping all the details under the phone number node,keep all the details of a particular user under a unique user uid which you can generate using firebase auth Check your logs to see whats the error... please post the errors displayed in the logs as well Without that,we dont know where the problem lies

Comment: Please add it to your question the entire error that you get.

Comment: It's Firebase Database error: Invalid token in path. And the invalid token is the period in "Phone No."

Comment: invalid token is the period in phone no?

Comment: what does that mean?period in phone no

Comment: please edit your question and post the logs as well...

Comment: You can get the actual cause of the error from `task.getException()`.

Comment: Yes, in your code where you put "Phone No." into a map, there. I did. Hopefully it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the period in "Phone No.", Firebase considers that an invalid token. Future Reference you can call task.getException(); and it will give you more of a reason why it failed. Edited. Hope that clears things up for you, if not feel free to ask away.

> W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /Users/mnum failed: DatabaseError:
>   Invalid token in path W/Exception:
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database
>   error: Invalid token in path
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:234)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities$1.onComplete(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:243)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$6.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:404)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6196)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

```
private void AddAcc(final String nam, final String mnum)
  {
    final DatabaseReference Rootref;
    Rootref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(mnum).exists())) {
                HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
                userDataMap.put("Name", nam);
                userDataMap.put("Phone No.", mnum); //Change "Phone No." to "Phone No"
                Rootref.child("Users").child(mnum).updateChildren(userDataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });


            } else {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Number is Already Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```